# webpack cannot load module jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, webpack

I am trying to import jquery in typescript using webpack. This is what I did.

```
npm init -y
npm install -g webpack
npm install ts-loader --save
touch webpack.config.js
```

In the file, I wrote this

```
module.exports = {  
  entry: './app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then create the `app.ts` and write the following

```
import $ = require('jquery');
```

then I `npm install jquery --save` to load the jquery component.

then when I execute `webpack` it gives me cannot find module 'jquery' message.

```
ts-loader: Using typescript@1.6.2
Hash: af60501e920b87c93349
Version: webpack 1.12.2
Time: 1044ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.39 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app.ts
(1,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.
```

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Nice question etiquette. Very to the point. Loved reading / answering it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

You need the jquery definitions:

`tsd install jquery --save`

Also you need to have a tsconfig.json:

`tsc -init` will generate one for you. But I recommend:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Also you need to install typescript

`npm install typescript -save`

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work. webpack can directly load npm component if I am correct. BTW, I love your youtube video. :)

Comment: Thanks, It is working now. Still I want to know that, is webpack reading node_modules automatically?

Comment: you can always create an alias in your webpack config

e.g. 

   ' resolve: {
      alias: {
        myNpmModule: path.join(__dirname, '/node_module/myNpmModule/dist/myNpmModule.min')'

Comment: `is webpack reading node_modules automatically` for `require` calls yes.